# Is there a query analyzer in SQL Server 2005 Express edition?

Tags: sql-server-2005, query-analyzer

I have downloaded the SQL Server 2005 Express edition and I was not able to fine query analyzer to run the queries or design the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download [Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961) (Or the [2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593) version). It is also possible to design the database and run queries inside Visual Studio.

Comment: but it will not support windows 7 64bit :(

Comment: Why not? There is a 64 bit version

Comment: in the link provide by you contains as belowSystem requirements
Supported operating systems: Windows 2000 Service Pack 4, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1, Windows XP Service Pack 2

Comment: Im pretty sure it'll work in windows 7. But otherwise you can always use [SQL Server 2008 Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593), it'll support 2005 databases also.

Comment: I tried 2005 but it says incompatible with OS , just downloading 2008 now

Comment: myself is wrong, i downloaded Management Studio 2005 and its working fine. Probably i download wrong versoin before.